# List existing server farms

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How do we list the server farms that exist in an Azure resource group? We have tried running `azure -h` to discover server farm commands. Specific commands exist for web apps, virtual machines, storage, and other resource but not for server farms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

```
azure resource list -g MyResourceGroup -r "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms" --json
```

## Explanation

It turns out that this is a `resource` command. Here is the syntax:

```
resource list -g <resource-group> -r <resource-type> --json
```

The `--json` part formats the output as JSON for readability.

The trick is to discover the `<resource-type>` name. One way is to first show the available providers and then we show the contents of a particular provider. The challenge is knowing which provider to inspect.

```
azure provider list
azure provider show Microsoft.Web
```

Another way is to list all the resources within a particular resource group. The challenge is that the output is quite verbose.

```
azure resource list <resource-group>
```

Good luck.